# Having Issues with Imported Components in React

Tags: reactjs, express, import, components

[The Image of what I've been facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOvXl.png)how to solve react issue of react component is defined but never used even when i tried using the component, but it keeps on saying the same thing.
I tried it for several times but it keeps on showing the same thing. I watched videos on Youtube but none of that match the problem am facing talk more of solving my problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure components names should have uppercase names like ContactCard, not contactCard

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I see two points to improve.

First of all, component names must start with an Uppercase.
So, instead of

```
src/addContact.js

import addContact from './addContact'
<addContact />
```

You should have

```
src/AddContact.jsx

import AddContact from './AddContact'
<AddContact />
```

Even StackOverflow understands that, see how the color of the code is different?

This change should fix your problem.

Also, it's good practice to use `.jsx` instead of `.js` for React Files (which are JSX Elements, thus .jsx).